# Asp.NET MVC in subfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have searched here, googling (with bing;)) and try all the things i have found but i 
dont get it running.

I have a subfolder created on my webspace at discountasp.net like "MySite". Then i 
made a virtual directory with the control panel. I published the Site with Visual 
Studio to the path
http://blablabla.com/MySite/. My Domain is pointed to this path too.

It looks good but the links like /Home/About/ becomes /MySite/Home/About/ and thats 
(of course) doesnt work.

How can i change that ? I think its an routing issue.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Pointing my Domain directly on the subfolder and defining a 
Outbound rewrite rule on iis solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To create your URLs you should use

```
@Url.Action(actionName, controllerName)
```

This will use the routes you specified and it will create correct URLs.

You can also use

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName)
```

To include images and stylesheets use

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/...")
```

Comment: i have deployed the empty "internet application" mvc project and the links are already created like this "@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")"